# Formatting markdown table with numeric and integer columns

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

How can knitr::kable() ignore to format an integer column and format all the ohter numeric columns?

Example:

`knitr::kable(x = as.data.frame(rbind(c(1L, 21.211), c(2L, 31.233))), format.args = list("digits" = 2, "nsmall" = 2, "big.mark" = ".", "decimal.mark" = ",", "scientific" = FALSE))`

It returns:

`[1] "|   V1|    V2|" "|----:|-----:|" "| 1,00| 21,21|" "| 2,00| 31,23|"`

And I what an output like this:

`[1] "|   V1|    V2|" "|----:|-----:|" "| 1| 21,21|" "| 2| 31,23|"`

Thanks

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949768/r-vary-by-row-the-rounding-of-digits-produced-by-knitrkable

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
But I'm looking for a more "automated" approach.. Maybe it is possible to wirte some logic which can handle this based in the mentioned post.

Answer (score 2):

`knitr::kable` always applies the same format to all numeric columns, so your only choice is to do the conversion to character columns before calling it, as J_F's reference suggested.

I doubt if it could be completely automated.  The dataframe you're starting with has only `numeric` columns; the `integer` values are converted to `numeric` by `c()`.  (You could have avoided this by constructing the dataframe differently.)  Assuming you have some way to construct a vector indicating which columns you want formatted in which way, you can do it automatically something like this:

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1L, 21.211), c(2L, 31.233)))
intcolumn <- c(TRUE, FALSE)  # This is hard to automate

for (i in seq_len(ncol(df))) {
  if (intcolumn[i])
    df[[i]] <- format(df[[i]])
  else
    df[[i]] <- format(df[[i]], digits = 2, nsmall = 2, big.mark = ".", 
                      decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)
}
knitr::kable(df, align = "r") # right align as for numeric column
```

This produces

```
| V1|    V2|
|--:|-----:|
|  1| 21,21|
|  2| 31,23|
```